# Simple .net core app won't build on linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following simple application. When I attempt to build it, I get the following error:

```
[jwan@xps datamigrator]$ dotnet --list-sdks
3.1.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
[jwan@xps datamigrator]$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.4.0+e901037fe for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(88,5): error NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'arch-x64' is not recognized. [/home/jwan/code/datamigrator/DataMigrator.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(88,5): error NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'arch-x64' is not recognized. [/home/jwan/code/datamigrator/DataMigrator.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(88,5): error NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'arch-x64' is not recognized. [/home/jwan/code/datamigrator/DataMigrator.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(88,5): error NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'arch-x64' is not recognized. [/home/jwan/code/datamigrator/DataMigrator.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(88,5): error NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'arch-x64' is not recognized. [/home/jwan/code/datamigrator/DataMigrator.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(88,5): error NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'arch-x64' is not recognized. [/home/jwan/code/datamigrator/DataMigrator.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    3 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.70
[jwan@xps datamigrator]$
```

As you can see, I already have the .NET Core SDK installed and it is version 3.1.1 that I have installed.

I'm not sure why it doesn't build.

Answer (score 2):

> There's a patch in the Arch Linux bugtracker for the arch-x64 issue:
>
> https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/65128

*found at [https://github.com/jellyfin/jellyfin/issues/2243](https://github.com/jellyfin/jellyfin/issues/2243_)*